Running astra-cli setup command returns "UnsatisfiedLinkError: jdk.internal.io.JdkConsoleImpl.echo(Z)Z"
I have installed Astra DB on macOS Sonoma using Homebrew
brew install datastax/astra-cli/astra-cli

I am running astra setup now but getting the following error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jdk.internal.io.JdkConsoleImpl.echo(Z)Z [symbol: Java_jdk_internal_io_JdkConsoleImpl_echo or Java_jdk_internal_io_JdkConsoleImpl_echo__Z]
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni.access.JNINativeLinkage.getOrFindEntryPoint(JNINativeLinkage.java:152)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni.JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.nativeCallAddress(JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.java:54)
    at java.base@21.0.1/jdk.internal.io.JdkConsoleImpl.echo(Native Method)
    at java.base@21.0.1/jdk.internal.io.JdkConsoleImpl.readPassword(JdkConsoleImpl.java:101)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.io.ProxyingConsole.readPassword(ProxyingConsole.java:117)
    at com.dtsx.astra.cli.config.SetupCmd.execute(SetupCmd.java:75)
    at com.dtsx.astra.cli.core.AbstractCmd.run(AbstractCmd.java:89)
    at com.dtsx.astra.cli.AstraCli.run(AstraCli.java:280)
    at com.dtsx.astra.cli.AstraCli.main(AstraCli.java:255)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/sa346b79c.invokeStaticInit(LambdaForm$DMH)


There is a known issue when running the Astra CLI setup command in interactive mode for some of the latest JDKs that leads to the UnsatisfiedLinkError.
As a workaround, please specify your database token using the --token option so it can connect to Astra, for example:
$ astra setup --token AstraCS:AbC...:123...

If the token is valid, you should see the following output:
[OK]    Configuration has been saved.
[OK]    Setup completed.
[INFO]  Enter 'astra help' to list available commands.

Then verify that the Astra CLI setup is complete using the config list command, for example:
$ astra config list
+-----------------------------------------+
| configuration                           |
+-----------------------------------------+
| erickramirez...@...com                  |
+-----------------------------------------+

These steps should allow you to get past the error. Cheers!

Thanks a lot for the prompt response Erick. This solved my problem
